# Spring Security antMatchers doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, filter

I have Spring Security configuration as below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.ss.userservices.security")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            // Custom JWT based security filter
            .antMatcher("/user/**")
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            // disable page caching
            httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Bean
    PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter voter() {
        ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        return new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(
                expressionAdvice);
    }
}
```

Although I have `antMatcher` is `/user/` but **all** requests go through above filter, not only request match with `/user/` expression.